# PHP Echo Fails in Quotes

Tags: php, forms, post, echo

Here's the code:

```
<form method="POST" action="<? echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

It displays as HTML:`<form method="POST" action="<? echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

PHP works on the rest of my code but this one has me itching my head

EDIT:

Here is the code to display it:

```
<?
$AssignedTo = $_POST['id'];
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) // if the form was submitted, display their name
{
// Action to be completed once the form is submitted
}
else // form hasn't been submitted, so display the form
{
echo '<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h2>**** - Add </h2>
</form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: That will work just fine.  More information is needed here.

Comment: check for opened quotes in the previous code or opened php tag eg: <?php..... <?php ?>

Comment: Also note that `$PHP_SELF` isn't a valid variable by itself (you'd need to define it).  See the [list of reserved variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php) and the [list of reserved constants](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php).  The information you're looking for is in `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`: see [the docs on `$_SERVER`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already echoing the string wrapping it in another PHP block is unnecessary and won't be parsed

```
<?
$AssignedTo = $_POST['id'];
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) // if the form was submitted, display their name
{
// Action to be completed once the form is submitted
}
else // form hasn't been submitted, so display the form
{
echo '<form method="POST" action="'.$PHP_SELF.'" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h2>**** - Add </h2>
</form>';
}
?>
```

That should work.

Comment: Didn't notice that, I thought it would echo it as HTML and therefore would need wrapping again.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Should it not be `<?php` rather than `<?` ?</strike>

What happens if you use

`<? echo "action='".$PHP_SELF."'"; ?>`

(So you wrap the action inside the echo)?

Using single quotes ' ' makes the PHP complier treat the whole thing as a literal string, so it will never echo the variable referenced by $PHP_SELF, but the actual string "$PHP_SELF"

(Also you've got nested PHP Tags? That makes no sense)

```
echo '<form method="POST" action="'.$PHP_SELF.'" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h2>**** - Add </h2>
</form>';
```

**Alternative Method:**

```
printf('<form method="POST" action="%s" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h2>**** - Add </h2>
</form>', $PHP_SELF);
```

Comment: you have missing double quote before semicolon

Comment: @infinity: Cheers :) (Not that it's relevate now)

Answer (score 0):

<s>First use `<?php` also check for opened quotes in the previous code. If you post the rest of the code would be easier.</s>

Nested PHP tags very wrong:

```
<?php
$AssignedTo = $_POST['id'];
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) // if the form was submitted, display their name
{
// Action to be completed once the form is submitted
}
else // form hasn't been submitted, so display the form
{
echo '<form method="POST" action="'.echo $PHP_SELF.'" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h2>**** - Add </h2>
</form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Already done that but still doesnt work, so thats why I tried <?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure short tags are allowed to execute php?

Comment: Yeah I Used it higher up in my code and it doesn't display that.

Answer (score 0):

Does <`?php .... ?>` work?

The `<?` syntax is configurable: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: <?php does not work for my code above but neither does <? and strangely enough it works higher up the page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't embed PHP open tags within PHP itself

```
echo '<form method="POST" action="',$PHP_SELF,'" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I tend to avoid the `,` syntax in an `echo` statement and use `.` concatenation instead. This means that it is easy later on to assign the string to a variable instead of printing it with `echo`.